# Google maps marker infowindow a href not rendering as a link

Tags: google-maps

I have successfully managed to make xml from mysql and present markers on a map (wo-hoo).

The script includes a infowindow with some basic data. I want to have the URL open en new window with the external URL.

The URL and the a href tag shows beautifully - and that's the issue - I want to be able to click on it :)

Could someone please help me with the code to do this? Bear in mind I have used a week to get the markers from the db. I'm in no position to rebuild the code (I hope).

[This is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84SnX.jpg)

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, 10.0),
      zoom: 3
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('mapxml.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var country = markerElem.getAttribute('country');
          var url = markerElem.getAttribute('url');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var text = document.createElement('url');
          text.textContent = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + name + "</a>";
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're working with custom html elements, the following

```
  var text = document.createElement('url');
  text.textContent = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + name + "</a>";
```

won't work. You should try instead

```
  var text = document.createElement('a');
  text.href=url;
  text.textContent = name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Now how to make the link open new tab _blank :)

Comment: just set `text.target='_blank'`